# How do I write a function that returns true if every integer in the array is different?

Tags: c, string

I have to write a function that will return true if every integer in the array is unique (different). So, I've tried correcting my for loops/my if statement and I've tried running the tests that I wrote. But, the test for a string with an integer appearing more than once still fails. I've reviewed my code but I still can't find the problem.

```
#include "in.h"

int in(int input[], int size)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
   {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
      {
         if (input[i] == input[j])
         {
            return 0;
         }
      }
   }

   return 1;
}
```

Here are my test cases:

```
#include "in.h"
#include "checkit.h"

void in_tests(void)
{
   int input[3] = {2, 4, 5};
   int answer;

   answer = in(input, 3);
   checkit_int(answer, 1);

   int input1[4] = {1, 3, 4, 1};
   int answer1;

   answer1 = in(input1, 4);
   checkit_int(answer, 0);
}

int main()
{
   in_tests();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about sorting the array first, then compare consecutive elements.

Comment: your function is backward; it indicates whether there is any pair which of differing values.

Comment: In my class, we haven't learned how to sort an array. So I don't think I can do that. :(

Comment: just as a side question, most of the examples in the answers below that say they are O(n2) complexity are not. what are they? or are they?

Comment: your checkit_int calls are wrong you are supposed be passing the size of the array as the second parameter not 1 or 0.. don't know what that means

Comment: Oh, no, I called the function "in" from the code above. And I assigned an integer variable "answer" to the return value of the function. (the function returns an integer). And in my function, if it was true, it returned a 1 and if it was false, it returned a 0. So I compared "answer" (the integer variable I assigned to the function) with what I expected, a 1 or a 0.

Comment: [Naive vs Sorted vs Hashtable](http://ideone.com/GKzjL4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without sort, an O(n<sup>2</sup>):

**j begins with i+1.**

```
int IsDiff(int array[], int count)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1;j<count;j++)
        {
            if (array[i] == array[j])
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean array[i] == array[j]?

Comment: So I've edited my code above to correct the for loops, but the tests for the program still fail. :( Specifically, when the array of integers has values that appear more than once. What could be wrong with my code??

Comment: @Karen your second checkit_int(answer, 0) should be checkit_int(answer1, 0)

Comment: WHOA...careless mistake, I think that was the problem, THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 2):

If space is not an issue, then we can have a O(n) solution using a hashtable. Start storing each element of the array in a hashtable. While inserting elements, make a check to see if it already present in the hashtable ( which takes O(1) time.) If the element is already present, then return false immediately, else iterate until the end of array and return true.

Comment: but what about the internal complexity of the hashtable calls?

Answer (score 1):

actually, thats not why your function doesn't work. the main reason is because currently you are checking if any pair DONT match, which would be great if you wanted to see if all the elements matched, but you want to do the opposite, so you want to check the opposite, if any pair DOES match.  so first change your if to be

```
if(input[i] == input[j]) return false;
```

if one pair is equal then you know that your test has already failed so there is no need to check the remaining pairs, just return false there and then.

the only other thing to do is to sort out your loops so that you only iterate over each pair once and don't compare a value against it's self. to do that change the for loops to be:

```
for(int i =0; i<size-1; i++)
   for(int j=i+1; j<size; j++)
```

then if you  make it to the end of the function, it means no pair as matched, so just return true;

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) as well.. but I added this function that makes the code more understandable...

```
int unique(int input[], int value,int size){
    int times=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(input[i]==value){
             times++;
             if(times==2)
                return 0;
        }
    }  
    return 1;
}

int in(int input[], int size)
{
   int x, answer;

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {  
      if(!unique(input,input[i],size))
          return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: There seems no bool in C. you need to return int instead?

Comment: yeah it's better to turn this to C code rather than C++ and this also feels a bit slow as a because you are not bubble sorting this

Comment: C has `bool`, but you have to include `stdbool.h`.

Comment: You need to explain your answer, so that there's some education value here. Otherwise, it's just a copy/paste answer to homework (that's clearly indicated as such in the comments to the original question). @AhmedMasud: The question poster indicated that sorting wasn't possible, as they haven't covered that in class yet. See the comments to the original question.

Comment: I think the function name helps understanding what it does. If the questioner is interested, it will be easy for him to understand. I didn't think it needs an explanation (I'm supposing that the questioner understands the code he wrote)

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, try this:

```
#include "in.h"

int in(int input[], int size)
{
   int answer = 1;

   for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
   {  
      for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++)  //check everything above your current 
                                        //value because you have already checked 
                                        //below it.
      {
         if (input[i] == input[j])
         {
            answer = 0;                  //If any are not unique you
            break;                       //should exit immediately to save time

         }
      }
      if (answer == 0)
          break
   }
   return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at it (very simple and inefficient though):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int uniq_int(int arr [], int size)
{        
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                return 0;

    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    int arr [] = {1, 2, 4, 3, 5};

    (uniq_int(arr, 5)) ? printf("Unique!\n") : printf("Not...\n");
    /* the above can be written more traditionally like this:
    if (uniq_int(arr, 5) != 0)
    {
        printf("Unique!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not...\n");
    }
    */

    return 0;
}
```

This will compare every member of the array against the rest, starting from the first
and comparing it against the next one and so on until the end of the inner loop.

Then we start the outer loop again but this time we compare the second element of the array against the ones after it.

As soon as a match is found the function will return and there won't be a need to compare the other elements. Otherwise the outer loop will go on until the last element and once that's reached it will exit and return 1, meaning every member is unique.

It has a complexity of O(n^2) as the set is processed twice for each member in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

## Thinking about the problem

let's say you have an array like this: `int array[] = { 3, 1, 4, 8, 2, 6, 7, 7, 9, 6 };`

if you start with the first element you need to compare to the rest of the elements in the set  ; so 3 needs to be compared to 1, 4, 3... etc.

if 3 is unique you need to now go to 1 and look at the remaining elements, but next time around you don't need to worry about the 3 ; so your *value under consideration* (let's call that V) needs to be each of,  array[0] to array[N-1] where `N` is the size of `array` (in our case 10);

But if we imagine ourselves in the middle of the array, we'll notice that we have already compared previous elements to the current element when the previous element was the *value under consideration*.  So we can ignore any elements "behind" us; which means comparison has to start the each time with the INDEX of current value under consideration (let's call that k) and compare it to values starting with the NEXT index and going to the end of the array ; so pseudo-code for our array of 10 it would look like this:

```
int is_a_set(int array[]) 
{
   for ( k = 0; k < 10-1 ; k++ ) { /* value under consideration */
      v = array[k]; 
      for ( m = k+1 ; m < 10; m++ ) { /* compared to the remaining array starting
                                     * starting from the next element */
           if ( v == array[m] ) { /* we found a value that matches, no need to 
                                   * to continue going, we can return from this function
                                   */
                 return true; 
           }
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

now you can use something like:

```
if ( is_a_set(my_array) ) {

}
```

You should be able to use this to figure the rest of your code out :-)

NOTE: a collection with unique elements is called a `set` so I named the function is_a_set

HINTS: convert size of the array (10) into a parameter or a variable of some sort